# makefile error. Multiple files not found

Tags: android, linux, makefile, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am cross compiling an executable file on Ubuntu (my desktop) for Android based Intel Platform to update firmware of a peripheral. During the make process and I am getting bunch of errors below:

```
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lm
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lc
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/home/waleed/sources/intel_cht_repo/out/host/linux-x86/poky/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
```

My guess is, that during build it is looking for files in wrong location and it needs to be fixed. 
Can anyone point out the error and its fix?

Comment: you need to include your makefile in the body of your Q. Or if you use debug mode `makefile -v` (I think), you'll see the cmd that is being executed preceding all of these error messages. Edit your Q to include that expanded command and it should be easy to understand what the problem is. Good luck.

Comment: Use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.